# Ajax image upload php handling

Tags: php, ajax, image-uploading

I have two image upload options one for icon and another for image, i have made a custom ajax image upload function in jquery, which send values to php for processing. i am getting image upload to work properly i.e if icon is clicked only icon is uploaded and if image is clicked only image is uploded, my problem is i am getting both value as set in php which is causing error in not selected(icon or image) field.

my codes are:

**html**

```
<form name="change" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="icon" type="file" />
<input name="image" type="file" />
</form>

<div id="icon"><img src="---" /></div>
<div id="image "><img src="---" /></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**jquery(Ajax)**

```
$('#icon img').click(function() {
    $('input[name=image ][type=file]').val(null);
    $('input[name=icon][type=file]').trigger('click');
});

$('#image img').click(function() {
    $('input[name=icon][type=file]').val(null);
    $('input[name=image ][type=file]').trigger('click');
});

$('input[name=icon], input[name=image ]').change(function() {
    change();
}); 


function change(){
var formData = new FormData($('form[name=change]')[0]);
formData.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: (function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
    }),
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
}
```

**php**

```
if(isset($_FILES['icon']) && !empty($_FILES['icon']) && $_FILES['icon'] !== ''){
echo 'icon set'.'<br />';
}
else{
echo 'icon not set'.'<br />';
}

if(isset($_FILES['image ']) && !empty($_FILES['image ']) && $_FILES['image '] !== ''){
echo 'image set'.'<br />';
}
else{
echo 'image not set'.'<br />';
}
```

If any one icon or image is selected to upload, I am getting result as.

```
icon set
image set
```

Please See and suggest what is causing error in php.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to && !empty($_FILES['icon']) ie middle condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys "image" and "icon" are keys to arrays about the upload, so they are set, not empty, and not strings === "". Try this:

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

And see if you get what you're expecting. Also, could be formData object - Google for "php formData"

Comment: finally got it to work like this `if(isset($_FILES['icon']) && !empty($_FILES['icon']['name']))` thanks your idea worked.